# Remove '(' and text which follows from a string

Tags: php, string, replace, trim

Goal, to trim all text starting with the a left parenthesis '(' from a string. I've read through stack for the last hour, php.net, googled, I've tried using trim, ltrim, rtrim, strpos, preg_replace, etc. Everything that I have found so far has dealt with how to replace the text IF it is a know quantity - mine will vary.

Examples:
Text i want to keep (All of this i want to remove) as well as this...
Example 2:
Text 2 keep (text to remove 123)
Example 3:
Keep Please (123remove)

What is the best way to sanitize this string? The text which follows the first paren will be alphanumeric (letters, numbers, possibly even Exclamation points, etc). The only constant is the first paren '(', anything after i want to trim away/remove.

I am of novice level, I am not yet dealing with classes or jQuery, etc. I wish to do this on the server.

Thank you for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strpos` to find the first parenthesis and `substr` to get the substring until this position :

```
$str = 'Test keep (remove) remove';
$pos = strpos($str, '(');
$newString = '';
if ($pos !== false) {
    $newString = substr($str, 0, $pos);
}
echo $newString;
```

Output

`Test keep`

Comment: This appears to have worked, I don't exactly understand why/how, but this works.  I see that we are using strpos to check the $str for the '(' character. If the character is not equal to '(' check next character until $pos matches (true). If match, from index of postion, replace with nothing? is that what/how this is happening?

Comment: And Yes, i ran several tests, this worked completely. Thank you.

Comment: @Chezshire There is no loop here. `strpos` find the first occurence of `(`. The false checks is here just for the case when there is no parenthesis at all in the string. In that case, `strpos` would return false, and an error would occurs on the `substr` call. By the way, in my example if there is no parenthesis, the new string becomes empty, but you can easily replace it as your need. :)

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. My instance will always have a starting paren, but this solution is very nice/universal in that it shows how it can be repurposed to a wider variety of uses/instances. I understand now. Thank you for your time and a great explanation.

Comment: further testing showed that there was still whitespace left at the very end of the string. As i'm using this to hand of a search variable, which has to match a stored variable, i needed to remove that single remaining whitespace. I did it like so: function cleanString_remove_all_after($str, $removeFrom){
 //$str = 'White Queen (earth 23) and more'; 
 $pos = strpos($str, $removeFrom); 
 if ($pos !== false) {
     $newString = substr($str, 0, $pos);
   //remove remaining whitespace before removed paren
   return rtrim($newString);
 }else { return $str;}
 
}

Answer (score 1):

Tested and works

echo preg_replace('@\(.*@i','',$string_tostrip);

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, it turned specialcharacters into encode i characters i think. -- this is the code i ran '$string_tostrip = "This is some text I want to keep (but i don’t want to keep any of this text in4432cluding the parens)."; 

preg_replace('@\(.*@i','', $string_tostrip);

echo $string_tostrip;

Comment: It might be an issue with posting your comment above but in the regex pattern you do not delimit the parenthesis with a slash so more than likely would cause an error with compiling the regEx

Comment: Thanks - this was uber helpful

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with preg_replace. You could try the following:

`preg_replace('\([^]*', $replacement, $subject)`

Answer (score 1):

$str =" Text i want to keep (All of this i want to remove)";

$s=explode("(",$str);

$concatinated_str =  $s[0];

echo $concatinated_str; // Text i want to keep

Comment: I thought this was a very elegant solution, it's certainly one I never would have thought to have explored. i wish i could vote for more then one solution.